# Convert MySQL date time representation to C++

Tags: c++, mysql, datetime

MySQL C++ Connector returns `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` as a sequence of bytes, a total of 40 bits in v5.6.4.
I want to be able to convert these bytes to a date representation either a data string or timestamp will do.

Here is an example of a returned bytes `"\344\017\t\004\000:"` as a string.
The [documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html) describes what bits represent each part of a date.

I want a generic or standard way of doing this.

For example, I could at least get the correct timestamp using `bitset<40>('\344\017\t\004\000:').to_ulong()` i.e 151259404. But this requires the argument to be at compile-time something like unsigned long. `bitset` process only strings of `1`'s or `0`'s.
Reinterpreting these strings to unsigned long does not really preserve the data and hence get wrong results.

Other approaches to achieving the same results are appreciated.

Comment: You should receive that value as a [struct MYSQL_TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-prepared-statement-data-structures.html)

Comment: @Botje I am looking for a C++ solution. It seems the C API is different from the C++ API.